# Rabbitmq commandline does not delete queues

Tags: rabbitmq

When I enter the following command with redirect to text file, as admin:

```
C:\Users\snoopy\Downloads>python.exe rabbitmqadmin.py -H dev-xxx.mydomain.com -P 15672 -u snoopy -p 123 delete queue name="foxbotXb44bacbd-b29c-449b-b5a5984ec3246c9b_control" -> CANNOTDELETE.txt
```

The contents of CANNOTDELETE.txt says the following:

```
 ERROR: Argument "-" not in format name=value
 rabbitmqadmin.py --help for help
```

If I don't redirect and just let the error display to the console I get the following ACCESS REFUSED

```
  C:\Users\snoopy\Downloads>python.exe rabbitmqadmin.py -H dev-xxx.mydomain.com -P 15672 -u snoopy -p Password123 delete queue name="foxbotXb44bacbd-b29c-449b-b5a5-984ec3246c9b_control" *** Access refused: /api/queues/%2F/quebotXb44bacbd-b29c-449b-b5a5-984ec3246c9b_control
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try in this way:

```
 $ ./rabbitmqadmin.py delete queue name='test' -H localhost -P 15672 -u guest -p guest 
    queue deleted
```

It should work.

**EDIT**

You don't have a permission, if I insert a wrong password (guest1) I have the same error:

```
$ ./rabbitmqadmin.py delete queue name='test' -H localhost -P 15672 -u guest -p guest1 
*** Access refused: /api/queues/%2F/test
```

Check your user permissions.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. But I still get ACCESS REFUSED
python.exe rabbitmqadmin.py delete queue name='foxbotXb44bacbd-b29c-449b-b5a5-984ec3246c9b_control' -H xxx-svc.vacationroost.com -P 15672 -u snoopy -p Password123

Comment: The admin just wrote me and said the snoopy account did not have perms to delete. She just granted them to me. So the command you have offered should work. Standby

Comment: hey gas, after being granted the right perms, I still couldn't delete. What I was missing was the -V switch. You must specify your vhost.

Comment: If you don't specify the `VHost` the API will use the default host "\". You can see in the URL defined as `/%2F/`.